# How can I get my text to perfectly fit my container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating one website and I have made a box where I'm placing my page content. Now my words were breaking at half at the end of the container so I used `white-space: pre;` and words weren't breaking at the end no more but I have another problem and the text is now not fitting 100% of container.

This is the website: https://5rand5.com/education/globetrot.php, the text is good, it takes 100% of its container but it words break at half at the end of line, so how can I make text like now fit whole container but words don't break at end of the container.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mainbox">
<img class="grow-shadow increase leftimage" src="assets/img/bubbles/firstb.png" align="left">

<p class="maintext textchange"><strong>GLOBETROT WITHH ARABIC</strong> is your online language classroom that
 gives you the opportunity to learn the Arabic
 language through Skype and/or Zoom wherever 
 you are and anytime you wish. Whether you are 
 an adventurer trotting around the globe and exploring 
 its wonders, an entrepreneur seeking flexible learning 
 hours, a fulltime mom/dad, or simply someone who aspires 
 to evolve in the comfort of their home while sipping on 
 warm coffee, this is your chance to finally take on the 
 opportunity of learning the Arabic language with a lot 
 of fun and flexibility and most importantly at your own pace and comfort. 
 You do not need to commit to physical place and space or to a particular time
 to learn the Arabic language and connect with its culture and people. With 
 Globetrot with Arabic, you can make the most of the increasing space-time 
 compression and cross social and cultural borders. All you need is a phone or a 
 computer, a set of earphones, good Wi-Fi and the enthusiasm to learn the Arabic
 language and the beautiful culture that comes with it.  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainbox {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -133px;
}

.leftimage {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 98px;
    margin-right: 152px;
    margin-bottom: 59px !important;
    left: 8.8em;
}

.increase {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.textchange {
    margin-bottom: -11em;
}

.maintext {
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size: 41px;
    padding: 186px;
}
```

Any help will really mean a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by your use of `word-break`. `break-all` will break at any character in the text to prevent overflow.

Try using `break-word` to help preserve the word when breaking. However, this may not fill the container 100% because every word length is different.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  width: 140px; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p.a {
  word-break: normal;
}

p.b {
  word-break: keep-all;
}

p.c {
  word-break: break-all;
}

p.d {
  word-break: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The word-break Property</h1>

<h2>word-break: normal (default):</h2>
<p class="a">Thisissomeveryveryverylong word. Words will break according to usual rules.</p>

<h2>word-break: keep-all:</h2>
<p class="b">Thisissomeveryveryverylong word. This text will-break-at-hyphens.</p>

<h2>word-break: break-all:</h2>
<p class="c">Thisissomeveryveryverylong word. This text will break at any character.</p>

<h2>word-break: break-word:</h2>
<p class="d">Thisissomeveryveryverylong word. This text will break at any word.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. You can just insert a code snippet right into your answer and I've done through my edit. Also, consider not linking to or citing W3Schools as it is well-known to have incomplete, outdated or flat out wrong information.

Comment: **word-break: break-word** not support on Firefox and Internet Explorer. **Reference Link**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

One way of ensuring your text line is 100% of the width is to use the text-justify property with inter-word. This puts white space between words to stretch to 100%, and won't break the words:

```css
.mainbox {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -133px;
}

.leftimage {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 98px;
    margin-right: 152px;
    margin-bottom: 59px !important;
    left: 8.8em;
}

.increase {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.textchange {
    margin-bottom: -11em;
}

.maintext {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;

    font-size: 41px;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
<img class="grow-shadow increase leftimage" src="assets/img/bubbles/firstb.png" align="left">

<p class="maintext textchange"><strong>GLOBETROT WITHH ARABIC</strong> is your online language classroom that
 gives you the opportunity to learn the Arabic
 language through Skype and/or Zoom wherever 
 you are and anytime you wish. Whether you are 
 an adventurer trotting around the globe and exploring 
 its wonders, an entrepreneur seeking flexible learning 
 hours, a fulltime mom/dad, or simply someone who aspires 
 to evolve in the comfort of their home while sipping on 
 warm coffee, this is your chance to finally take on the 
 opportunity of learning the Arabic language with a lot 
 of fun and flexibility and most importantly at your own pace and comfort. 
 You do not need to commit to physical place and space or to a particular time
 to learn the Arabic language and connect with its culture and people. With 
 Globetrot with Arabic, you can make the most of the increasing space-time 
 compression and cross social and cultural borders. All you need is a phone or a 
 computer, a set of earphones, good Wi-Fi and the enthusiasm to learn the Arabic
 language and the beautiful culture that comes with it.  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `word-wrap: break-word` prop, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>DummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyTextDummyText</div>
```